# iptables INPUT command

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, iptables, ping

On a ubuntu1, this is iptables command:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -j DROP
```

so on the other computer (xp1) I can not ping the ubuntu1.So this is OK.
But On ubutnu I [[ can ]] ping xp1. and I think this is not OK. I do not have problem with ping request but I have problem with ping replay from xp1. why that caommand does not drop the replay of ping which is an ICMP packet.

update:

oh sorry . I did a mistake . I did not see the replay on terminal!!! I just see the replay on wireshark.!!!

Comment: duplicate question asked on unix & linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally the INPUT chain have rule to allow related/established traffic

```
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

When Ubuntu issue ping traffic to XP, the reply from XP is related traffic that accept by above rule.